# Adjusting python auto-complete behavior

Tags: vim, autocomplete, flask, aptana, python-idle

I have been using Aptana with pydev and IDLE to learn python2.7. And it has done a fair job of helping me to learn, except for when I came across this [microblog](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) tutorial. In it there is a line `from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` which leads to a `db = SQLAlchemy(` line, in Aptana there is no help, no doc string, no examples of what could go in there. Even worse, all of this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = ROLE_USER)
```

Is in red, no idea how to pull it apart to learn its syntax. However, when I do:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
```

In IDLE, I am getting auto-completion, doc strings, I can see what else can go in there, I can learn.

I thought the answer would exist with a new IDE like environment, I got it in my head that VIM might be helpful. I am on windows, so GIT, MinGW, TortoiseHG, _vimrc, vimfiles, {autoload,bundle}, pathogen.vim, jedi-vim, building vim from source (for some reason the ones I kept finding didn't have python enabled) were not easy task, considering first time exposure and all at once. So I have a vim that can edit python code, and `from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` in vim has the same result as in Aptana, no help.

Can someone explain to me why IDLE is able to help but Aptana/Pydev and Vim cannot? Can someone show me how they can help?

This is what is in flask.ext.__init__().py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    flask.ext
    ~~~~~~~~~

    Redirect imports for extensions.  This module basically makes it possible
    for us to transition from flaskext.foo to flask_foo without having to
    force all extensions to upgrade at the same time.

    When a user does ``from flask.ext.foo import bar`` it will attempt to
    import ``from flask_foo import bar`` first and when that fails it will
    try to import ``from flaskext.foo import bar``.

    We're switching from namespace packages because it was just too painful for
    everybody involved.

    :copyright: (c) 2011 by Armin Ronacher.
    :license: BSD, see LICENSE for more details.
"""


def setup():
    from ..exthook import ExtensionImporter
    importer = ExtensionImporter(['flask_%s', 'flaskext.%s'], __name__)
    importer.install()


setup()
del setup
```

So in my case from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy translates to "look in site-packages for the flask_sqlalchemy.py and in that file find SQLAlchemy" which is, in this case, a big class. How can I make Aptana and vim see this, like IDLE does?

Comment: +1 for digging into this so well!  You may need to file a bug against Aptana's / Your VIm plugin's Python support for this one.

Comment: And, just FYI, you can get around the issue for now by skipping the import hook and importing from `flask_sqlalchemy` instead of the nicer-looking `flask.ext.sqlalchemy`.

Comment: If IDLE works why are you trying to use Vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) solved it, but I used `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` as my Variable value and I deleted and restored my interpreter in pydev, seems to have worked.